# Right way to fit image to CALayer contents in swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calayer

I am new to programming.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

var l: CALayer { 
    return myView.layer
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpLayer()
}

func setUpLayer() {
    l.contents = UIImage(named: "IMG_3682.jpg")?.CGImage
    l.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
}
```

The image appears way bigger than myView.

I got imges with various sizes and ratios.
and I want to fit them into UIView.layer
What is the right way to do it?

thanks

Comment: Remove `l.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter`

Answer (score 0):

Remove line:

```
l.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
```